# BoW in OpenCV using precomputed features

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, feature-detection

I need to do BOW (bag of words) but I only have the described keypoints of the images.
For the moment, I have obtained the vocabulary using:

```
cv::BOWKMeansTrainer bowtrainerCN(numCenters); //num clusters
bowtrainerCN.add(allDescriptors);
cv::Mat vocabularyCN = bowtrainerCN.cluster();
```

So now I need to do the assignment but I can't use the compute function because it calculates the descriptors of the images and I already have that. Is there any function to do the assignment or have I to compute it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have built the vocabulary (codebook) using `cv::BOWKMeansTrainer::cluster()` method, you can then match a descriptor (with suitable size and type) to the codebook. You first have to choose the type of matcher you need with a norm to use. (see [opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher))

For example, with `cv::BFMatcher` and `L2 norm`

```
// init the matcher with you pre-trained codebook
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher > matcher = new cv::BFMatcher(cv::NORM_L2);
matcher->add(std::vector<cv::Mat>(1, vocabulary));
// matches
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
matcher->match(new_descriptors,matches);
```

Then the index of the closest codeword in your codebook for the new_descriptors[i] will be

```
matches[i].trainIdx;
```